# Efficient python loop structure to repeat something once

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have some code that I'm trying to have the option to repeat once, with a couple of preparation & cleanup steps before/after the repeat. I have a loop structure that works, but strikes me as quite inelegant:

```
twostepswitch = int(not(twostep))

while twostepswitch < 2:
    print("Do the thing")

    if twostepswitch < 1:
        twostepswitch += 1
        print("Prepare to repeat")
        continue
    elif twostep != 0:
        print("Cleanup from repeat")
        break
    else:
        break
```

When `twostep = False` this returns:

```
Do the thing
```

And when `twostep = True` it returns:

```
Do the thing
Prepare to repeat
Do the thing
Cleanup from repeat
```

This is what I expect and intend. But again, I'd like to do it less clunkily.

`twostep` is a universal setting that I use in multiple places in the code (including later repeats of this loop structure), which is why I'm avoiding modifying it directly.

Any ideas on how to do in a more elegant or Pythonic way?

[EDIT: obviously `print("Do the thing")` is placeholder for much longer code, so I'd like to not simply repeat that block.]

Comment: Your program need is not yet clear.  What values can `twostep` have?  If this is merely a matter of doing something once versus twice, it's a simple function and `if`, not a clunky `while` loop.  If it's more, this is still likely a `for` loop` and an internal flag check.

Comment: @Prune changed the `twostep` syntax to be Boolean so hopefully it's a bit clearer. It's a matter of doing it just once, vs. twice with some prep / cleanup before / after the second iteration. Could you give an example of what the loop structure you're suggesting would be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let go of the mechanics for a moment: what is the natural-language description of what you're doing?  It seems to be "if `N` is 0, do `blah` once and quit; otherwise, do `blah` once, do something else, do 'blah` again, and do the last thing ... and quit.

This suggests that `blah` belongs in a function.  In fact, let's put all the code into functions, so that the "long code" pieces don't interfere with understanding the main logic flow.

```
do_twice = int(input(...)) != 0
do_the_thing()
if do_twice:
    prepare()
    do_the_thing()
    cleanup()
```

I expect that you can handle making the functions from your existing code.

Comment: Hmm. The `blah` or `do_the_thing()` code block is sizeable and contains several complex custom functions already. I considered putting it in some umbrella functions before but am loathe to nest custom functions too deep / complex. Is it considered reasonably Pythonic to take a block like that and just throw it into a no-argument function like `do_the_thing()`?

Comment: Yes -- encapsulating a complex process is usually good programming practice in any language.  In this case, it is especially useful, as it allows you to invoke that process from two distinct contexts.

Comment: @TYLim "The blah or do_the_thing() code block is sizeable and contains several complex custom functions already." that should definitely be refactored and split across multiple functions within `do_the_thing`

Comment: @SuperStormer I'm not sure what you mean - there are _already_ multiple custom functions within that block, which I've tried to keep to mostly workflow control while putting the specific work within those custom functions.

Comment: Where the Zen of Python says "flat is better than nested", it's talking about *the code itself*, not the way that the functions call each other. Using more functions is usually making things *less* "nested". While it's also true that "simple is better than complex", sometimes you really just can't avoid the complexity, and it has to go somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this:

```
def func(*args, **kwds):
    print(f"do the thing {args[0]}")

def prep(f, num):
    limited = [f] * num

    def func(*args, **kwds):
        if not limited:
            return 
        f = limited.pop()
        return f(*args, **kwds)

    return func

twostepswitch = prep(func,  2)

twostepswitch(1)
twostepswitch(2)
twostepswitch(3)

twostepswitch = prep(func,  3)

twostepswitch(11)
twostepswitch(22)
twostepswitch(33)
```

#### output:

```
do the thing 1
do the thing 2
do the thing 11
do the thing 22
do the thing 33
```

Could even be done with a @-based function decorator version of it as well, except that a decorator with an input (num = 2, num =3) is a little bit funky-looking in Python.

And this is a version allowing you to fire optional prepare/cleanup functions.

```
    print(f"do the thing {args[0]}")

def prep(f, num, prep=None, cleanup=None):
    limited = [prep, f, cleanup] * num

    def func(*args, **kwds):
        if not limited:
            return 
        prep = limited.pop(0)   
        f = limited.pop(0)
        cleanup = limited.pop(0)

        if prep:
            prep() 
        res = f(*args, **kwds)
        if cleanup:
            cleanup()
        return res

    return func


def prepa():
    print("prepa")

def cleanup():
    print("cleanup")

twostepswitch = prep(func,  3, prep=prepa, cleanup=cleanup)

print("\n\n")

twostepswitch(11)
twostepswitch(22)
twostepswitch(33)
twostepswitch(44)
```

#### output:

```
prepa
do the thing 11
cleanup
prepa
do the thing 22
cleanup
prepa
do the thing 33
cleanup
```